# Is a one-dimensional vector space orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working on an assignment where we need to orthonormalize bases, but one of the problem is a one-dimensional subspace of R3. I know the definition for orthogonal relies on the scalar product, but there's only one vector. My instinct is there's no way it can be anything other than orthogonal, but I can't think of a good reason why it's orthogonal. Maybe treat the zero vector as the other vector in the scalar product? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Give us the one dimensional vector space as a span and I'll answer you :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a subspace being orthogonal? Orthogonal to what?

Comment: span{(1,-1,2)} is what I calculated. The space is defined as  W = {(x, y, z) ∈ R3|3x + y − z = 0 and 2y + z = 0}

Comment: Orthogonal to the other elements that define the basis. But, there's only one element of the basis, so I have no idea what it's meant to be orthogonal to.

Comment: A set $\{u_1,u_2,\dots,u_n\}$ is said to be orthogonal if for all $i\neq j$ you have $\langle u_i,u_j\rangle = 0$.  A set with one vector is trivially an orthogonal set since there exist no examples of two nonequal vectors whose inner product is nonzero.  You can extend the above definition to a set being orthonormal if $\langle u_i,u_j\rangle = \delta_{i,j} = \begin{cases} 0&\text{if}~i\neq j\\ 1&\text{if}~i=j\end{cases}$

Comment: Thanks so much! I guess it doesn't violate the definition should've been my first thought.

Answer (score 1):

An ordered basis $B = (u_{1}, \dots, u_{n})$ of an inner product space is *orthonormal* if:

- Each element has unit length ($u_{j} \cdot u_{j} = 1$ for each $j$).
- Any two distinct elements are orthogonal ($u_{i} \cdot u_{j} = 0$ if $i \neq j$).

The two conditions together are often summarized by writing $u_{i} \cdot u_{j} = \delta_{ij}$ (the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) symbol).

In your situation, you want to focus on the "normal" (i.e., *normalized*, or *unit-length*) part of "orthonormal", not the "ortho" (orthogonal, or perpendicular) part.

That is, divide your basis vector by its magnitude.